# CSS verically align text in <a> anchor when display type block

Tags: css

I'm not too sure this can be done without pseudo elements - but what do I know.

I have a tab element which is an `<LI>`.

Inside each LI there is an `<A>`.

I want to achieve 2 things:

1. Make the A element fill the space of its parent LI. The height is
   known but the width is variable.
2. Centre the text vertically,

Obviously this is easily done with 1 liners, simply add `display:block` and `line-height` to the anchor.

However, I need to **allow for line wraps too**.

So, to recap: fill the available space in the parent and vertically align text within its own block.

I can use flexbox or whatever, but at the moment, I can do one or the other not both.

Comment: It would be useful if you provide something you've already got to show us a little snippet that displays the current behaviour so we can go from there

Comment: The problem being randy that its each to achieve centralisation with 1 line (I've highlighted the method in the post) but not 2 or more. At the moment, I'm fiddling with pseudo elements but I've nothing concrete to put on the table. The problem I'm having with the pseudo approach is that the link target is not being applied to the pseudo element, so I can achieve both of my aims, but the pseudo of A, at the moment is not a valid clickable link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using flex-box to wrap the items, giving the `li` elements a height of `50 px`, and then the `a` tag a line-height of `50px`.

- Because of the line-height, the text is vertically centered.
- Because of flex-box, the items wrap multiline.

```css
ul {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

ul li a {
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  line-height:50px;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great idea randy - I'll need to change the line height for 2 liners but I'm detecting that anyway, so this will probably work for me too. It can be done with pseudo elements (although I've yet to get a working version), but it relies on pointer events, which IE10 does not have, so I think I'll have a go at your solution.